What happens when you hide from a creature with Truesight?
I've just read through the Rules Glossary in the new PHB and don't quite understand the interaction between Hiding and Truesight. In the 2014 rules there was no interaction to be had, as none of Truesight's features referenced anything related to hiding. However in the new rules successfully hiding explicitly grants the Invisible condition which Truesight is explicitly able to see.
This however does not seem to make sense, if you think about it a bit further. Suppose a Rogue takes cover behind an obstacle such as a big rock which would grant him both total cover and making him heavily obscured and thus enabling him to hide. In this state the Truesight creature can not see him, as they cannot see through solid objects (this is further clarified in this question about the old version) He then takes the hide action and rolls really well, succesfully gaining the invisible Condition. Now however, atleast if we go by the literal wording of the rules, the Truesight creature would suddenly be able to see him, as they can "see creatures and objects that have the invisible condition".
Can they now see him through the obstacle, just because he has that condition? Or is this some sort of oversight that might be clarified in future errata? Or are we maybe supposed to interpret that as the Truesight creature just not being fooled by hidden creatures?

Truesight still needs line of sight to work
Any creature trying to look at another creature that is Heavily Obscured has the Blinded condition against it, as explained in the Glossary entries for those 2 terms. Thus it automatically fails all attempts at trying to see the concealed creature, such as with the new Search action. Therefore even with Truesight you cannot see a heavily obscured creature, invisible or not (unless the obscurement is darkness which Truesight explicitly bypasses).
As stated in that older question Truesight does not allow you to look through objects (that aren't illusions). So the text of it being able to "see" invisible creatures must be prefaced with the fact that this only works if they don't have the blinded condition against those creatures. They cannot see an invisible creature (no matter how they got that condition) if they don't or cannot look at them. This is also implied by the text in the starting paragraph of Truesight, emphasis mine:

your vision pierces through [...]

I.e. Truesight only applies within line of sight. E.g. if a creature with Truesight were to close their eyes or be hit by the first part of a Blindness/Deafess spell, they would no longer be able to see through any invisiblity as they don't see those creatures, period. This is also true for Truesight's other capabilites, e.g. if they don't look at an illusion they don't see through it.
This is further supported by the text in the Invisible condition, which states that its benefits apply, "unless a creature can somehow see you". Meaning an invisible creature (be it from hiding or actually being invisible) behind a wall, rock or other solid, opaque obstacle still benefits from the Invisible condition against a Trueseeing opponent, as long as it remains fully concealed.
